# Running Running PARSEC 2.1 on gem5

Tags: python, linux, shell, gem5

I am running with this kernel and configuration:

```sh
./build/ALPHA/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py \
    --num-cpus=16 \
    --cpu-type=DerivO3CPU \
    --caches --l2cache \
    --l2_size=512kB \
    --l2_assoc=16 \
    --num-l2caches=1 \
    --mem-size=1GB \
    --maxtime=2 \
    --cpu-clock='1GHz' \
    --take-checkpoints=0,100000000000 \
    --script=run_scripts/dedup_16c_simsmall.rcS \
    --kernel=/home/fur/gem5/full_system_images_ALPHA/binaries/vmlinux_2.6.27-gcc_4.3.4 \
    --checkpoint-at-end \
    --max-checkpoints=2
```

Should I change the kernel file (`vmlinux_2.6.27-gcc_4.3.4`) for each workload (i.e. bodytrack, canneal, dedup, etc.) or it's the same for all workloads and, so, I should change script file only?

For each running, this gives me the same hits and miss numbers for all workloads.

Comment: Should be the same kernel, why it would be different :-)? Please try to describe more clearly what problem you observed. Here's another setup that could be of interest: https://cirosantilli.com/linux-kernel-module-cheat/#parsec-benchmark

Comment: thanks for replying ,

Comment: i put same kernel as Parsec installation with each time change script based on benchmarks , put i get same results for no. of hits at L2 caches ! get same results from different benchmarks!

Comment: Exiting @ tick 91790537000 because a thread reached the max instruction count , but gave  me same results when i changes :--script=run_scripts/blackscholes_16c_simsmall.rcS  or any other scripts for Parsc workloads!